# How do you download the latest Windows Defender platform engine for offline PC, as well as the definitions?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-update, windows-defender

How do you download the latest Windows Defender platform engine, as well as the definitions?

It is for computers that are not online yet, I would like to do this for both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

I have found this page https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/defenderupdates however, it talks of "security intelligence files" and the linked page "Release notes" https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/definitions/antimalware-definition-release-notes shows only threat detections, not an update for the Windows Defender engine.

I would like the Defender platform downloads for 8.1 as well as Windows 10, is that possible?

Comment: Latest version at the top (W10)>>>>https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4052623

Comment: Windows 8.1>>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/anti-malware-platform-update-for-windows-defender-in-windows-8-and-windows-rt-d5a5f9c7-cedd-691d-3fb5-f2dea7367ce8

Comment: Windows 8.1>>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/anti-malware-platform-update-for-windows-defender-in-windows-8-and-windows-rt-d5a5f9c7-cedd-691d-3fb5-f2dea7367ce8

Comment: @ Moab Thanks, there are several files in KB4052623 (Version 4.18.2203.5) do I install them all? Does the order matter? Is there a more recent update for Windows 8.1? The latest date I see on that page is 2014. (I could not find a more recent download).

Comment: Just the latest date>>4-7-2022

Comment: @ Moab I see that date on the first linked page for Windows 10. On the Windows 8.1 webpage, the linked download pages say 5-12-2014. Is there no more recent download available for the Defender platform engine in Windows 8.1?